# How do I remove the hover image smoothly as do by .hide(2000) method?

Tags: jquery

This is the code and I want to remove the hover image smoothly. When I hover one image the larger version of the image is showing. And I hover out then the larger image is gone suddenly.

But I want to this lager image to be gone smoothly. I tried with the `.hide(2000)` method, but it does for the first time hover. But in the other time the larger image is not gone.

The HTML code:

```
    <a href="oneTN.jpg"><img src="one.gif" alt="some text"></a>
    <a href="twoTN.jpg"><img src="two.jpg" alt="some text"></a>
    <a href="threeTN.jpg"><img src="three.jpg" alt="some text"></a>
```

The jQuery code:

```
 $(function() {
    $('a').hover(function(e) {
      var href= $(this).attr('href');
      $('<img id="larger" src="'+ href +'" />').css('top', e.pageY + 20).css('left', e.pageX + 20).appendTo('body');
 }, function() {
      $('#larger').stop().remove();
   });


   $('a').mousemove(function(e) {
      $('#larger').css('top', e.pageY + 20).css('left', e.pageX + 20);
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this might be what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/7xb2vc14/2/

actually I just added the `fadeIn() - fadeOut()` function and changed a bit how the javascript `css` part was written.

```
$(function() {
    $('a').hover(function(e) {
      var href= $(this).attr('href');
      $('<img id="larger" src="'+ href +'" />')
          .fadeIn(3000)
          .css({
            'top' : e.pageY + 20,
            'left' : e.pageX + 20})
          .appendTo('body');
 }, function() {
      $('#larger').stop().fadeOut( "slow", function() {
            $(this).remove();
  });
});


   $('a').mousemove(function(e) {
      $('#larger')
          .css({
                'top' : e.pageY + 20,
                'left': e.pageX + 20
          });
    });
 });
```

you just asked for `an image to be gone smoothly` so I think `fadeOut()` does the trick. But your function gets the image means it loads the image and then it removes it again and maybe has to do this a couple times and maybe you are loading verry big images so it's verry bad. Imagine if someone trys to load the page on a mobile device with a low band width.

Long story short: if you can just add a hidden image and then google for `jquery show(), hide(), toggle()` so the image gets loaded ONCE and remains in the DOM and all you do is show and hide it. But do not remove it and load it again.

Comment: Thanks you very much. This is working. But this shows the image suddenly. I want to show the image smoothly and fade out smoothly both. It can be done?@caramba

Comment: Thanks a lot @ caramba

Comment: @ChayanBiswas you are welcome, glad it helped. Please do not forget to  mark the answer as the right answer.

Comment: But I don get the way to mark this as right ans. Will you help me to do that?@caramba

Comment: @ChayanBiswas where the answer begins on the left you have arrows and right below the arrows should be a checkmark to click on almost like visible here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow